# React Native run-android Build failed

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I want start my react native app, but everytime when i try this i have some error:

[**//ERROR PHOTO//**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EFny.png)

---

I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7xdbsjFGtU&list=PLA_u3gtc5zsyEgLaTLY7clKiM2IRU4ndI&index=2) guide for configurated Android SDK, but I didn't have some parameters when configuring it in: `SDK Manager` -> `SDK Tools`
I haven't:

1. `GPU Debugging Tools`
2. `Android SDK Tools`
3. And i haven't Folder `Support Repository`

[//**ANDROID SDK PHOTO**//](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt3iW.png)

---

And this my Path settings screen

[**//PATH PHOTO 1//**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4GL3.png)

[**//PATH PHOTO 2//**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rb8Q.png)

[**//PATH PHOTO 3//**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL4va.png)

Comment: the error is "unsupported class file major version 60" which is usually caused by a incompatible java / gradle version could you share those?

Comment: @Nestoro, I'm not good at this, I hope this is what you need
``javac -version``
``javac 1.8.0_301``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issues as you does.
My solution is to install JDK according to the documentation

[image]

```
choco install -y nodejs.install openjdk8
```

After that, run again the project and it works!

Comment: You're welcome :) Do upvote my answer so that more people who faced this issue got their solution